# Detect Wake Locks programmatically

Tags: android, wakelock

We develop a `SDK` that is heavily dependent on the `location APIs` of Android OS and Google Play Services.

We have detected that there are too many wake ups causing Android Vitals to launch alerts in our clients' developer console. In order to solve or mitigate the issue, I would like to measure the amount of `wake locks` that the application holds over time, so I can see if my code changes are effective or not.

I've been using an app called `"Wakelock Detector"` which is great, however I need more information regarding the wake locks themselves, so I would like to code a tool to debug the issue myself.

However I've been unable to find documentation regarding how to read this information from Java (only `adb` commands). It is possible to do so? How the app `"Wakelock detector"` works?

Comment: For testing purposes you could download a apk decompiler and check in the `Wakelock Detector` app itself. You should not sell software based on that code though without checking the licenses of the `Wakelock Detector`

Comment: Thanks @JensV. It uses reflection to read values from the following internal class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/BatteryStatsImpl.java , So no public APIs. My conclusions so far: use reflection, or try to run and parse adb commands from Java Code.